# Complex Factorial Equaling One

Tags: factorial, gamma-function

For what complex values of $z$ is $$z! =1? $$ Are they even all known? Are there finitely many or infinitely many?

(Yes, the trivial $z$ are 0 and 1. )

Comment: A minor notational nit. $z!$ is not defined, except for natural numbers, but $\Gamma(z+1)$ is.

Comment: Yes, the factorial is to be interpreted as the value assigned to it by the gamma function.

Comment: For people who want to see a few sample values, take a look at [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+gamma%28z%29+%3D+1+over+complex+numbers).  (Not an answer, but may help some people.)

Answer (score 15):

I assume what you mean is $\Gamma(z+1) = 1$.

Here's a plot of the curves $\text{Re}(\Gamma(z+1)) = 1$ (blue) and
$\text{Im}(\Gamma(z+1)) = 0$ (red).  Each intersection of a red and blue curve
corresponds to a solution.  Assuming the pattern continues, it certainly appears that there are infinitely many.

[image]

The first $10$ solutions in the first quadrant are
$$ \begin {array}{c}  1\\ 
 3.213486150+ 4.253693352\,i\\ 4.447352283+
 6.904660210\,i\\  5.449043370+ 9.238727110\,i
\\  6.328673500+ 11.39926303\,i\\ 
 7.129370000+ 13.44405135\,i\\  7.873424830+
 15.40369196\,i\\  8.574168470+ 17.29686175\,i
\\  9.240338285+ 19.13602021\,i\\ 
 9.878036600+ 20.93000503\,i\end {array}  
$$

Here's a plot of the first $151$:

[image]

It certainly looks like they lie on a curve.

EDIT:  OK, something analytic can be said.  The asymptotic

$$ \Gamma(z) \sim \sqrt{2\pi} e^{-z} z^{z-1/2} 
= \sqrt{2\pi} \exp(-z + (z - 1/2) \log(z)) \ \text{as}\ |z| \to \infty$$

holds for $|\arg z| < \pi$ with the principal branch of the log.
If $z = t e^{i\theta}$ with $\theta \in (0, \pi/2)$, 
$$\text{Re}(-z + (z-1/2) \log(z)) = t \ln(t) \cos(\theta) - (\theta \sin(\theta) + \cos( \theta)) t - \ln(t)/2 $$
If this is $\log(1/\sqrt{2\pi})$, indicating that $|\Gamma(z) \approx 1$,
then $\ln(t) \approx 1 + \theta \tan(\theta)$.  Note that the right side
goes to $\infty$ as $\theta \to (\pi/2)-$.  The roots should be approximately on this curve.  And indeed, here is the previous plot together with the curve
$\ln(t) = 1 + \theta \tan(\theta)$ (in red):

[image]

Comment: Do they fit on some approximative line? Or is the pattern more ugly when you look at it on a wider scale?

Comment: How did you obtain this graph? ( so that I can do it myself in the future)

Comment: In Maple: plots:-implicitplot([Re(GAMMA(x+I*y+1))-1,Im(GAMMA(x+I*y+1))],x=-5..15,y=0..15,colour=[blue,red],gridrefine=3);

Comment: Thanks. The values do seem to lie on a straight line...

Comment: Thanks again, Robert Israel. Such an observation must somehow be provable!

Comment: It may be worth looking up the properties of $\log\Gamma(x)$ rather than $\Gamma(x)-1$ directly, since they both have the same zeroes but the former seems a bit more 'natural.' @Assaultous2

Comment: There's also a couple solutions, as shown on your contour plot, for $z=-2.62665992489826\pm 0.4692180538174468 i$.

Comment: Very nice heuristic, Robert Israel.